# Count total number of objects in list ordered by the number of associated objects

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two models

```
class User
 has_many :subscriptions
end
```

and

```
class Subscription
 belongs_to :user
end
```

one one of my pages I would like to display a list of all users ordered by the number of subscriptions each user has. I am not to good with sql queries but I think that

```
list = Users.all.joins(:subscriptions).group("user.id").order("count(subscriptions.id) DESC")
```

dose the job. Now to my problem, when I try to count the total number of objects in `list`, using `list.count`, I get a hash with `user.id` and subscription count, like this

```
{11 => 5,
8 => 7,
1 => 11,
...}
```

not the total number of users in `list`.. `.count` works fine if I have a list sorted by for example user name (which is in the user table). I would really like to use `.count` since it in a module for pagination thats in a gem but any ideas is great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just use a single query to finish this:

```
User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as num_subscriptions
                              FROM subscriptions
                              GROUP BY user_id
                            ) AS temp
                            ON temp.user_id = users.id")
    .order("temp.num_subscriptions DESC")
```

Basically, my idea is to try to query the number of subscription for each `user_id` in the subquery, then join with `User`. I used `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, because there will be several `users` which don't have any `subscriptions`

**Improve option**: You can define a scope inside `User`, it would be more beautiful for later usage:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :subscriptions

 scope :sorted_by_num_subscriptions, -> {
   joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as num_subscriptions
                                  FROM subscriptions
                                  GROUP BY user_id
                                ) AS temp
                                ON temp.user_id = users.id")
   .order("temp.num_subscriptions DESC")
 }
end
```

Then just use it:

```
User.sorted_by_num_subscriptions
```

Answer (score 0):

When `group`ing, the `count` method changes it's behavior and indeed, instead of returning the total count of records, it returns **a hash of the counts for each group** (see the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count) for more info). So what you get with `list.count` is simply a hash of the subscription counts for each user.

So, your query is correct and all you need is to sum up the individual counts in the groups. This can be done simply by:

```
total_count = list.count.values.sum
```

If it is the pagination code that calls just a bare `count` that makes the issue, usually the pagination code is able to accept a parameter with total count. For example, [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) accepts the `total_entries` parameter, so you should be able to pass it the total count like this:

```
list.paginate(page: 2, total_entries: list.count.values.sum)
```